# check array for limitations

Tags: php, forms, security

I am accepting form submissions.
To prevent spoofing of the form I am using php isnumeric to verify that the posted values contain only numeric values.

I would like to check also:

1) that the posted values array contains max 1000 values (because no user would buy more than 1000 items!)

2) that the size of a single array key is composed of max 20 numbers (bigint unsigned max length)

how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 1:

```
if (count($posted_values) <= 1000)
{
   ...
}
else
   echo "Error";
```

Point 2:

Did you mean [PHP_INT_MAX](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) ?

If yes, just do:

```
foreach($posted_values as $value)
```

and then check that `$value` is less or equal than `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Comment: point 2: I was using the bigint unsigned max size. So I did __________if ($element > 18446744073709551615) .. anyway your answer guided me to find the solution! thanks!